# Can artifactory browse the contents of multi-level zip packages?

Tags: artifactory

Artifactory: 7.38.8
Artifactory can browse the contents of the one-level zip package. But if there is a two-level zip package in the contents, the contents of the two-level cannot be expanded and browsed.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your observation is correct. We can expand the archive file only once in the tree browser of Artifactory. But it might be the intended behaviour. If we have a file opened in archive utility app(zip/Win RAR), from which we can expand the sub-archived file in an archive file, and see the contents. But Artifactory can only show the list of the files up to one level.